# Poloniex New Websocket API

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, api, websocket, poloniex

I am trying to use the [new websocket API with Poloniex](https://poloniex.com/support/api/). Wamp is now deprecated and there is very little information around how to do a simple call for real time public data such as volume etc.

I have found this code which seems to implement this socket, but appears in bitestream. When I run the code it calls the header fine and gets a response header fine as well and seems to send and receive data but then closes the socket. How can I subscribe to the volume channel and have decoded streaming data?

```
import websocket
import threading
import time
import json
from threading import Thread


def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")


def on_open(ws):
    print("ON OPEN")
    def run(*args):
        ws.send(json.dumps({'command':'subscribe','channel':1003}))
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
        ws.close()
        print("thread terminating...")
    threading.Thread(target=run).start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://api2.poloniex.com/",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)

    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()


Am expecting a streaming connection to volume data but get this:

ON OPEN
send: b"\x81\xa9.)\x1d\xb8U\x0b~\xd7CD|\xd6J\x0b'\x98\x0cZh\xda]Jo\xd1LL?\x94\x0e\x0b~\xd0OGs\xddB\x0b'\x98\x1f\x19-\x8bS"
[1003,1]
unorderable types: float() > NoneType()
send: b'\x88\x82fWPGe\xbf'
### closed ###
```

Polo seems to think I am subscribed:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange because I can't reproduce your error, try this:

```
import websocket
import threading
import time
import json
from threading import Thread


def on_message(ws, message):
    json_msg = json.loads(message)
    channel_id = int(json_msg[0])
    if (channel_id==1003) and len(json_msg)>2:
        print("volume update")
        print(json_msg[2][2])


def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")


def on_open(ws):
    print("ON OPEN")
    def run(*args):
        ws.send(json.dumps({'command':'subscribe','channel':"1003"}))

    threading.Thread(target=run).start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://api2.poloniex.com/",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)

    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

Which give you:

```
[...]
ON OPEN
send: '\x81\xab\xc0\xe6~#\xbb\xc4\x1dL\xad\x8b\x1fM\xa4\xc4D\x03\xe2\x95\x0bA\xb3\x85\x0cJ\xa2\x83\\\x0f\xe0\xc4\x1dK\xa1\x88\x10F\xac\xc4D\x03\xe2\xd7N\x13\xf3\xc4\x03'
volume update
{u'USDT': u'5340084.934', u'ETH': u'914.931', u'XMR': u'194.895', u'BTC': u'1927.227', u'USDC': u'1275367.951'}
```